# REST APIs - XML Parsing with Java on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am new to Android Development.

For my project, I need to use "REST APIs" outputting XML. What will be the best way of using that in Java for Android?

Can anyone provide some options with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best library out there is Simple XML: http://simple.sourceforge.net/ Take a look at the examples... it will allow you to easily parse and generate XML from simple objects.

There will be others that recommend you to use SAX or XmlPullParser which comes in the Android SDK; however, I have developed many apps that uses XML REST APIs, and what I found is that SimpleXml makes me like 200% more productive.